# How to reprocess json file into single line per records?

Tags: python, json

```
{
"name": "16287e9cdf", 
"width": 500, 
"height": 325, 
"width": 1024, 
"height": 665
},
{
"name": "16287e9cdf", 
"width": 500, 
"height": 325, 
"width": 1024, 
"height": 665
}
```

How to reprocess those value in json like following , with the help of Python, for Spark to analyze?

```
{"name": "16287e9cdf","width": 500,"height": 325,"width": 1024,"height": 665}
{"name": "16287e9cdf","width": 500,"height": 325,"width": 1024,"height": 665}
```

I need:  1. each {.......} is a single line; 2. delete "," between lines.

I have 2,000,0000 records in a Json file. How to do....

Comment: What is the difference between those two snippets, except that one has split lines and the other doesn't?

Comment: Your data is not a valid JSON. You can use any JSON validator (e.g., http://jsonlint.com/) to check this. Any processing must be done with the valid data.

Comment: Whats the size of file? MB, GB? Are you on windows or linux?

Comment: @Cody If you can open it in memory that should work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can read it in memory you can do it like so:

First append `[` and `]` with sed from command line to first and last lines respectively to make it a valid json.

```
$ sed -i '1i [' filename
$ sed -i -e '$a]' filename
```

Then you can process it with python like so:

```
import json

with open('filename', 'r') as f:
    a = json.load(f)

with open('new_filename', 'w') as f2:
    for b in a:
        f2.write(str(b)+'\n')
```